# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.durabledeeplink', reason: 'Configure Durable Deep Link fails

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-dynamic-links

Update to latest Firebase iOS SDK and it cannot work. The app will throw this error when I run it: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.durabledeeplink', reason: 'Configure Durable Deep Link fails.`

Comment: mskobe,  I got the same error -- let me know if you find anything.

Comment: Sure, will do! It has bothered me for 3 or 4 hours. It is really annoying. Hope someone in the firebase team can help us.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying error probably has something to do with your `GoogleServices-info.plist` file missing an important entry (probably `API_KEY` or `CLIENT_ID`).

You can most likely fix this by just re-downloading the `GoogleServices-info.plist` file again. Go to the Firebase console, select your project, click the little gear icon, select "Project settings" then for your iOS app, download the plist file again.

Delete the old one from Xcode, drag the new one in, and you should be good to go.

As mskobe noted you can also fix this by removing the Invites and Deep Links libraries, but that probably isn't the answer you're looking for if you ever want to use those libraries. :)

Comment: I tried this one but when I'm downloading the GoogleServices-info.plist file, the file is not found. Should be the app in the app store? cause mine is still in development and I added "0" to the app store id.

Answer (score 1):

@ScotShinderman I make it work. I don't know exactly what happened there, but here is the way I fix it. 
1. Clean all the derived data & module cache
2. Delete all the pod library I have installed and delete all the firebase relate libraries from Podfile. 
3. Only add the firebase component that I need to use:

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
```

4. install pod libraries and build project, works

Comment: similar experience -- in my case it was removing pod 'Firebase/Invites' that seemed to do the trick.  From the error message it makes some sense as Invites could be related to the 'deep link' stuff.